# How to delete a specific item in Firefox cache?

Tags: firefox, browser, cache

I am asking a general question on whether there is a way to do it.

However, the specific problem I am battling is that I went to http://foo.com and at the time the server was having problems and redirected me to http://foo.com/error.htm.  The website was fixed and responds correctly, but Firefox still redirects me to http://foo.com/error.htm.

If I go to http://foo.com in private mode or in a different browser, the page renders fine.  But in regular mode, Firefox just always redirects me to the initial redirect page.

P.S. Firefox 60.x, Windows 10

So how do I remove this piece of browser cache (without nuking the entire cache)?

Comment: How about selecting a foo.com entry in History and right click to "Forget About This Site"? I haven't used this to discriminate what is in the cache since I usually clear it, but it might work. BTW, you should add FF version and OS to your question, in case it matters.

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh the webpage with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> it should load it again without using the cache.
If you type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and click on webstorage you should be able to delete specific webpages from the cache.

Comment: There is no way to do that.  Ctrl+F5 will refresh the redirected page, not the original URL..